# One liner for tab between xargs output

Tags: formatting, sh, xargs

I am looking for ways to insert tab `\t` between the xargs output.

In my case I have 950 lines of recorded numbers as following in several files,

```
cat test.l
2.35549
6.08890
8.09881
9.55697
11.25489
12.69488
13.02548
13.95622

cat test.l|xargs
2.35549 6.08890 8.09881 9.55697 11.25489 12.69488 13.02548 13.95622
```

Is it possible to replace the `whitespace` between arguments in xargs output to `\t`.
If I can replace then target program can process them easily.

From the manual I found that replacement of input delimiter (which is `\n`) is easy. Probably I should look for other command to get this done.

---

Updates:

One lame way is ,

```
cat test.l|xargs | awk '{print $1,"\t",$2,"\t",$3,"\t",$4,"\t",$5}'
```

which is very tedious.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `xargs`; just use `tr`:

```
tr '\n' '\t' < test.l
```

Comment: That is neat. Thank !